# How do i get this memory game preview to work?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I was following this youtube video called "Learn JavaScript by Building 7 Games - Full Course
". And I got up to 6 minutes where we are meant to view what has been accomplished in the browser, and I cant get anything to show but the title name, nothing else works, not even writing.
It is meant to be a memory card game preview and I am meant to see the blank cards I made as well as text saying "Score:" but I see nothing in any browser.

This is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Memory Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"><script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Score:<span id="result"></span></h3>

<div class="grid">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my javascript code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    //card options
    const cardArray = [
    {
        name: 'kyung',
        img: 'images/kyung.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'kyung',
        img: 'images/kyung.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'marmalade',
        img: 'images/marmalade.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'marmalade',
        img: 'images/marmalade.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'jangmi',
        img: 'images/jangmi.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'jangmi',
        img: 'images/jangmi.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'tadashi',
        img: 'images/tadashi.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'tadashi',
        img: 'images/tadashi.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'jason',
        img: 'images/jason.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'jason',
        img: 'images/jason.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'genki',
        img: 'images/genki.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'genki',
        img: 'images/genki.png'
    },
]

const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')

//create your board
function createBoard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
        var card = document.createElement('img')
        card.setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png')
        card.setAttribute('data-id', i)
        // card.addEventListener('click', flipcard)
        grid.appendChild(card)
    }
}
createBoard()
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
"// card.addEventListener('click', flipcard)" is supposed to be commented out because the video is not up to that part yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have `1 < cardArray.length` but that should be `i < cardArray.length`, in your `for` loop.

It causes an endless loop, as `1` is always less than `cardArray.length` (12).

Change:

```js
for (let i = 0; 1 < cardArray.length; i++) {
    // Code inside loop
}
```

To:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
    // Code inside loop
}
```

Or use a **more modern way** to loop through arrays:

```js
cardArray.forEach((_, i) => {
    // Code inside loop
});
```

Note that I used `_` to indicate that the value isn't used inside of your loop, but rather just the index.

---

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  //card options
  const cardArray = [{
      name: 'kyung',
      img: 'images/kyung.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'kyung',
      img: 'images/kyung.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'marmalade',
      img: 'images/marmalade.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'marmalade',
      img: 'images/marmalade.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'jangmi',
      img: 'images/jangmi.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'jangmi',
      img: 'images/jangmi.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'tadashi',
      img: 'images/tadashi.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'tadashi',
      img: 'images/tadashi.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'jason',
      img: 'images/jason.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'jason',
      img: 'images/jason.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'genki',
      img: 'images/genki.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'genki',
      img: 'images/genki.png'
    },
  ]

  const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')

  //create your board
  function createBoard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
      var card = document.createElement('img')
      card.setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png')
      card.setAttribute('data-id', i)
      // card.addEventListener('click', flipcard)
      grid.appendChild(card)
    }
  }
  createBoard()
});
```

```html
<h3>Score:<span id="result"></span></h3>
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work, nothing still shows.

Comment: I added a code snippet, note that I closed your first function. What is your expected result?

Comment: it works on this website, but when i use it from my own files in browsers it doesn't work.

Comment: You didn't close off your `<script>` with `</script>`. The `/` means closing.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close script tag:

```
<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"><script>
```

Your whole HTML code is written in script tag that will definitely throw Syntex Error.